# Is it possible not to allow iframe to show file download popup?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a code like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.upnp.org/download/UPNP_understandingUPNP.doc"></iframe>
```

When this code is rendered, browser file download prompt is shown to user. I'd want to prohibit iframe from showing this download popup.

Is it possible?

---

I'd want it as iframe's url is controlled by users, not site owner.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199269/prevent-browser-from-prompting-for-file-download-when-opening-css-file-in-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The *server* hosting the URL can decide if it wants to mark it as an attachment (suggesting that the browser to save it) or inline (suggesting that the browser should open it; using a plugin if one is available).

The *browser* decides how to handle it.

The *page* linking to it (even if it does so via an iframe) has no control over any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the download popup, you could use ajax instead of an iframe to load the url.